# How to go from wildcard to generic return type without unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, generics, casting

The following code is producing an `Unchecked cast` warning because of the cast of `(GenericKeyedObjectPool<String, T>)`.

As can be seen in the code, the wildcard (`? extends ConnectionBase`) and generic type (`T extends ConnectionBase`) are the same.

How can I get rid of the `Unchecked cast` warning and convert without warnings from the wildcard to the generic type?

```
private Map<String, GenericKeyedObjectPool<String, ? extends ConnectionBase>> poolMap 
     = new HashMap<>();

public <T extends ConnectionBase> T borrowObject(
        String guid, 
        Class<T> connClass) 
        throws Exception {
    GenericKeyedObjectPool<String, T> pool 
        = (GenericKeyedObjectPool<String, T>) poolMap.get(connClass.getName());
    return pool.borrowObject(guid);
}
```

Comment: *"As can be seen in the code, the wildcard (? extends ConnectionBase) and generic type (T extends ConnectionBase) are the same."* - **no**. Neither can that be seen right now nor can that theoretically be seen unless you change the type of `poolMap`. Either your entire class has to become generic on `T` or you have to cast because there is no guarantee what is added to the map is of type `T`.

Comment: @luk2302 so what would my `poolMap` type need to be changed to?

Comment: Just changed my comment, your class has to become generic, not just the method. The type it has to have is `Map<String, GenericKeyedObjectPool<String, T>>`

Comment: @luk2302 my class is an enum.  I guess I could change that to a class instead to ensure the type safety.

Comment: @luk2302 Is specifying the type at the class level the **only** way to achieve type safety here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is unsafe.

if A isConnectionBase

B extends A

C extends A

B and C are not safe to cast between.

To make the cast safe, you need to make it redundant by specifying the type of T at the class level to enforce it is same class throughout the class.